# Not able to generate png from from svg because of transform attribute by using angular5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, angular5, internet-explorer-11

I am not able to generate png from svg created in the application because of transform attribute. If there is no value in transformation, I am getting the svg. This problem I am facing in IE11.

```
    let targetElem = <any>document.getElementById('body');
    let nodesToRecover = [];
    let nodesToRemove = [];

    let svgElem = targetElem.querySelector('svg#svg-annotations')

    let parentNode = svgElem.parentNode;
        // let svg = parentNode.innerHTML.trim();
        let svg = '<svg width="100" height="100"> <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" transform="translate(295 157)" fill="yellow" /> </svg>';
        this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        this.canvas.setAttribute('id', '_canvas' + this.counter);

        canvg(this.canvas, svg);

        parentNode.appendChild(this.canvas);
        let data = this.canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 0.5);
        console.log(data);
        let blobData = this.base64toBlob(data.split(',')[1], 'image/png');
        saveAs(blobData, 'myblob.png');
        console.log(blobData);
        this.counter++;
```

Can anyone help me how to resolve this problem with transform? Any help will be much appraciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue is resolved by putting width and height to the required value. the problem was, translate property value is 297, 195 which is more than width and height given.